# How to fix "ImportError: cannot import name '_raise_dep_warning_if_not_pytest' from 'sklearn.utils.deprecation'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, pycaret

I am trying to use Pycaret to do classification for an imbalanced dataset

I installed Pycaret 2.3.1 and have sklearn 0.23.2

When I use the code

from pycaret.classification import *

I get the error

[image: Error Message Received]

Can you help me to fix this? Thanks in advance .

Comment: `_raise_dep_warning_if_not_pytest` might not be present in `sklearn.utils.deprecation`.

Comment: Yes , but how can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Comment: Tried it , didn't work